# Extract the tag list from blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info

Is there any way to download the [address-tags](https://blockchain.info/tags?filter=8) list as a file?
This would be very useful for a bitcoin data analysis project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the text and paste it directly into Calc, Excel or whatever spreadsheet-program you use.
They recognize the tabs as seperators.

Comment: I am trying to parse this page with java and htmlunit. It would be easy to store the parsed data for further analysis. Btw, thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you like to do it manually you could use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/export-to-csv/

Comment: I have finally written a code in java that makes use of htmlunit and parses the blockchain.info/tags page. The parsed data (address, tag, link, isVerified) can be stored to a database. This code is at [github](https://github.com/istovatis/BitcoinAnalyser/blob/master/src/BlockchainParser.java)